# Vote with Mongoid at Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, rate, vote

I've got a problem with my vote methods for comments. Im a begginer at RoR and waiting for your suggestions.

The error I get is:

> ActionController::RoutingError at /posts/51f7d1279fefa5405a000003 No
>   route matches {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"vote(1)",
>   :class=>"post__button--edit"}

My code:

comment.rb

```
class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :email, type: String
  field :body, type: String
  field :up_vote, type: Integer, default: "0"
  field :down_vote, type: Integer, default: "0"
  belongs_to :post

  validates_presence_of :name, :email, :body

  def self.add_up_vote
    self.increment(:up_vote, 1)
  end

  def self.add_down_vote
    self.decrement(:down_vote, 1)
  end
end
```

comment_controller.rb

```
.
.
.
def vote(a)
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])

    if a == 1
      comment.add_up_vote
      redirect_to @post
    elsif a == -1
      comment.add_down_vote
      redirect_to @post
    else
      redirect_to @post
    end

  end
```

routes.rb

```
Easyblog::Application.routes.draw do

  authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'home#index'
  end
  root :to => "home#index"
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
    member do
      post :mark_archived
    end
  end
end
```

Im waiting for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `a` here? I guess it's vote direction

You have to remove argument `a` from `vote` action and pass direction via `params` for link path.

Fox example:

```
vote_comment_path(@comment.id, dir: 1) # or dir: -1
```

More than that there is no route for `vote` action. You can describe it like so:

```
resources :comments do
  put :vote, as: :member
end
```

**upd** I would recommend you to read following guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

`action` in your path is not valid. You link should looks like

```
= link_to 'Yes', vote_comment_path(comment, dir: 1), method: :put
```

`vote_comment_path` can be different you could check it by `rake routes` command:

```
$ rake routes
```

Comment: changed and still the same problem.

Comment: I need to add, that the method (vote) is used in 'post' view (app/views/posts/show.haml) with:

@post.comments.each do |comment|
.
.
.
%td= link_to "YES", controller: "comments", action: "vote(comment, 1)", class: 'post__button--edit'

Comment: I've added more description to my answer.

Comment: It show me smthg like this:
post_comment_member PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id/vote(.:format) comments#vote

Comment: Yes. Try to read the section http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources and all the guide

Answer (score 0):

Try changing like this

```
Easyblog::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments do
      match :vote
    end
    member do
      post :mark_archived
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this in youre routes

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments do
    member do
      post 'vote'
  end
end 
 member do
  post :mark_archived
end
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to build your own voting system. Take a look at the [voteable_mongo gem](https://github.com/vinova/voteable_mongo)